# Alternative to create a new method a String object?

Tags: java, csv, refactoring

I'm facing with a issue: I have a csv file to prepare and extract values. Here is the code (and works fine):

```
public class Extract {

final int[] ID = new int[]{0, 10};
final int[] NAME = new int[]{15, 45};

public static void main(String args[]) {

  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\cnab.txt");        
  String line;

  while ((line = fis.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(getValue(line, ID));
      System.out.println(getValue(line, NAME)); 
  }
}

private String getValue(String line, int[] slice) {
    return line.substring(slice[0], slice[1]);
}
```

}

Until then ok , but I would like something more readable , elegant, such as:

```
System.out.println(line.getValue(NAME));
```

But we all know that String is final (and so should be). Anyone have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to have an enum where you've currently got int arrays:

```
public enum Field {
    ID(0, 10),
    NAME(15, 45);

    private final int start;
    private final int end;

    private Field(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public string extractFrom(String line) {
        return line.substring(start, end);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
System.out.println(Fields.NAME.extractFrom(line));
System.out.println(Fields.ID.extractFrom(line));
```

This means you can pass around fields (e.g. to have a set of required fields for validation) without them just being `int[]`, which could mean anything - and you can add any other custom methods and information you want. (For example, for validation you could have a `Pattern` field...)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class which would be a wrapper around `String` (i.e. composition instead of inheritance):

```
public MyString {

    private final String string;

    public MyString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return string.substring(0, 10);
    }

    // ...

}
```

I'd recommend different name than `MyString`, it should be something that describes what this object is. If you don't need any of `String` methods, this should be fine. If you need a few, you could simply delegate them

```
public MyString {

    // ...

    public int length() {
        return string.length();
    }

    // ...

}
```

If you need all, [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) has a `@Delegate` annotation that may sort out that problem, I am not actually sure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for some abstraction that will allow you to *query* the different columns in the file. Why not mimic `java.sql.ResultSet`? e.g.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./datacol.txt"));

    // Build the recordset for the file
    RecordSet rec = new RecordSet(file);

    // Iterate on the lines or "records" in the file
    while (rec.next()) {
        try {
            System.out.println(rec.getInt(FooField.ID)); // get the right type
            System.out.println(rec.getString(FooField.NAME));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

`RecordSet` class wraps the file and allow you to fetch the lines. For that, you will need to describe the file columns with some object that will be used by the `RecordSet`. Following is a descriptor as proposed by @Jon, with an `enum`, but it implements a simple interface `RecordField`. The purpose of this interface is to allow for different *field descriptors* to be used by `RecordSet`:

```
public interface RecordField {
    String getFieldValue(String line);
}

// Describe a specific file ("Foo") with its columns (or fields)
public enum FooField implements RecordField {
    ID(0,10),
    NAME(15, 45);

    private final int start;
    private final int end;

    private FooField(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFieldValue(String line) {
        if (line.length() < start || line.length() < end) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid line length for "+this);
        }
        return line.substring(start, end);
    }

}
```

Now the `RecordSet` class is quite simple and provides typed values for field access - here only `int` and `String` -:

```
public class RecordSet {

    private BufferedReader data;
    private String line; 

    public RecordSet(BufferedReader file) {
        this.data = file;
    }

    public boolean next() throws IOException {
        line = data.readLine();
        return line!=null;
    }

    public int getInt(RecordField col) {
        checkLine();
        String val = col.getFieldValue(line);
        return Integer.parseInt(val.trim());
    }

    public String getString(RecordField col) {
        checkLine();
        String val = col.getFieldValue(line);
        return val.trim();
    }

    private void checkLine() {
        if (line == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No current record");
        }
    }
}
```